# Use srcset to change links to images instead of the images themselves?

Tags: html, image, srcset

I want to have a static 100px thumbnail (it'll be 100px in all screen sizes), clicking on which a larger version (depending on the screen size) of the same image will be shown. So the thumbnail will essentially act as a link to the `srcset` variations. Is this possible?

```
<a href="/">
  <img src="thumb.jpg">
</a>


<img src="default.jpg" class="thumbnail" srcset="small.jpg 600w, medium.jpg 1000w large.jpg 2000w">
```

Comment: Can you provide your `srcset` variations and your breakpoints, please?

Comment: @Rounin I've updated the post with the thumbnail and the `srcset` variations separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a javascript event listener which listens for a click on the image.

When the image is clicked, you can add the `srcset` attribute.

The browser will do the rest.

**Example:**

```js
var thumbnail = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')[0];
var srcsetAttribute = document.createAttribute('srcset');
var srcsetValue = 'http://placehold.it/200x100 600w, http://placehold.it/300x100 1000w, http://placehold.it/600x100 2000w';
srcsetAttribute.value = srcsetValue;

function addSrcset() {
this.setAttributeNode(srcsetAttribute);
}

thumbnail.addEventListener('click',addSrcset,false);
```

```html
<img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Thumbnail - Click Me" />
```